# PrintWriter is throwing FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, printwriter

I have a method:

```
try {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(getResource("save.txt").toString()));

    writer.println("level:" + level);
    writer.println("coins:" + coins);

    writer.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And it throws this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/Users/lpasfiel/Desktop/Java%20Games/Jumpo/out/production/Jumpo/com/salsagames/jumpo/save.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:263)
at com.salsagames.jumpo.Variables$Methods.save(Variables.java:49)
```

It says the error is in the line with `PrintWriter writer = ...` The file definitely exists. (but that shouldn't be a problem, should it?). This method has worked for `.png`s in an ImageIcon, so I don't see why it would be any different. Could someone explain why this doesn't work and how to fix it?

Comment: have you tried to pass the full path to the `File` object? is that file in classpath?

Comment: It's in the same directory as the class, but I'll try the full path.

Comment: No, didn't work.

Comment: which path did you pass?

Comment: Originally it was `save.txt` but after your suggestion, it was `/com/salsagames/jumpo/save.txt` which is the correct location.

Comment: with full path I mean something like `C:/users/userX/.../save.txt`. Adjust this to your case and try again

Comment: No, it's inside the project structure.

Comment: yes, but it still has a full path... try it with that one. if it works, then the next step is to get it from the classpath

Comment: But it returns the path in the `getResource()` method. If you look at the error, it has where it is on the computer, but if you insist.

Comment: Nope, still no luck.

Comment: What happens if you replace the `.toString()` with `.toURI()` and deal with the checked exception? The `File` object can take a URI in one of its constructors.

Comment: If the file is packaged along with the compiled classes in a jar or war or whatever then you might not be able to write to it, it might work while your are developing using and IDE (eclipse / netbeans / ...). The way you are tying to write that file is not correct. Please tell us what you want to achieve and some might come up with a nice solution for you.

Comment: @SeverityOne Thank you! That was the issue. Would you mind putting that up as an answer?

Comment: There a spaces in your Filepath that have been replaced by %20.

Comment: @Ralf Renz That's who the Unix file-system works.

Comment: @Luke: now that you mention it. On Windows it would be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, this worked:

```
try {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(getResource("save.txt").toURI()));

    writer.println("level:" + level);
    writer.println("coins:" + coins);

    writer.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException | URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets look carefully at this line:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/Users/lpasfiel/Desktop/Java%20Games/Jumpo/out/production/Jumpo/com/salsagames/jumpo/save.txt (No such file or directory)
```

If you look at other examples of `FileNotFoundException`, you will notice that a typical message looks like this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /some/path/to/file.txt (No such file or directory)
```

or

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: dir/file.txt (No such file or directory)
```

In short, a typical "file not found" message starts with an absolute or relative file pathname.  But in your example, the message shows a "file:" URL.

I think that *that* is the problem.  I think that you have created a `File` using a URL string rather than a pathname.  The `File` constructor doesn't check this<sup>1</sup>, but when you attempt to instantiate the FileWriter, the OS complains that it cannot find a file *with that pathname*.

(The clues are that the supposed pathname starts with "file:", and that it also includes a %-escaped space.)

Solution:

Something like one of the following ... depending on what `getResource()` is returning.

```
  File file = new File(getResource("save.txt").toURI());
  PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
```

or

```
  PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(getResource("save.txt").openStream());
```

---

<sup>1 - And it shouldn't.  A URL string is actually a syntactically valid pathname.  Since a `File` is allowed to represent a file path that doesn't exist in the file system, there would be no basis for the `File` constructor to reject a URL string.</sup>